# Permissions error with CMake and CUDA

Tags: c++, cmake, cuda

I'm trying to build a project with a static library using CUDA along with C++ code. It needs to link with an external library (moderngpu). The CUDA and C++ code each independently work fine, and have been previously compiled with make. However, when trying to build the code with CMake (through CLion, if it matters), I get the following error:

```
Error running 'main': Cannot run program "/home/mnemonic/Programs/myProject/bin/src/CMakeFiles/hvm.dir/cmake_device_link.o" (in directory "/home/mnemonic/Programs/myProject/bin/src/CMakeFiles/hvm.dir"): error=13, Permission denied
```

I've been trying to solve this for days, but haven't been able to make any progress. It doesn't make sense that I'm getting a permissions error at all, and the `.o` file it's complaining about doesn't run when I set it to executable. My best guess is that it's some sort of linking issue. Any help would be appreciated.

`CMakeLists.txt`

```
CMAKE_MINIMUM_REQUIRED(VERSION 3.9 FATAL_ERROR)
PROJECT(myProject LANGUAGES CXX CUDA)

FIND_PACKAGE(CUDA 8.0 REQUIRED)

SET(CMAKE_CXX_STANDARD 17)
SET(CMAKE_CXX_FLAGS "${CMAKE_CXX_FLAGS} \
-Wall -Wextra -Wno-deprecated -Wfloat-equal -Wundef -Wcast-align -Wwrite-strings -Wlogical-op \
-Wmissing-declarations -Wredundant-decls -Wshadow -Woverloaded-virtual -Wpedantic \
-ffast-math \
")
SET(CMAKE_CUDA_COMPILER /usr/local/cuda-8.0/bin/nvcc)
SET(CMAKE_CUDA_FLAGS "${CMAKE_CUDA_FLAGS} \
    -Xcompiler -pthread,-fno-strict-aliasing,-g,-O2,-g,-fwrapv,-O3,-Wall,-fPIC \
    -gencode arch=compute_61,code=sm_61 \
")

ADD_SUBDIRECTORY(src)
ADD_SUBDIRECTORY(lib)
```

`src/CMakeLists.txt`

```
INCLUDE_DIRECTORIES(${CMAKE_CURRENT_SOURCE_DIR}/../include)
INCLUDE_DIRECTORIES(${CMAKE_CURRENT_SOURCE_DIR})

AUX_SOURCE_DIRECTORY(${CMAKE_CURRENT_SOURCE_DIR} source)

ADD_EXECUTABLE(stuff ${source})

TARGET_LINK_LIBRARIES(stuff LINK_PUBLIC thing thingKernels)
```

`lib/CMakeLists.txt`

```
INCLUDE_DIRECTORIES(${CMAKE_CURRENT_SOURCE_DIR}/../include)
INCLUDE_DIRECTORIES(${CMAKE_CURRENT_SOURCE_DIR})
INCLUDE_DIRECTORIES(
    /usr/local/src/moderngpu/include
    /usr/local/cuda-8.0/include
)

ADD_LIBRARY(thing STATIC
    ${CMAKE_CURRENT_SOURCE_DIR}/thing.cpp
)

ADD_LIBRARY(thingKernels STATIC
    ../include/cuda/thing.cu
    /usr/local/src/moderngpu/src/mgpucontext.cu
    /usr/local/src/moderngpu/src/mgpuutil.cpp
)

TARGET_INCLUDE_DIRECTORIES(thing PUBLIC ../include ${CMAKE_CURRENT_SOURCE_DIR})
TARGET_INCLUDE_DIRECTORIES(thingKernels PUBLIC ../include ${CMAKE_CURRENT_SOURCE_DIR})
```

For reference, this is the working `Makefile`

```
ifndef CUDA_VERSION
    CUDA_VERSION = 8.0
endif
ifndef COMPUTE_CAPABILITY
    COMPUTE_CAPABILITY = 61
endif

CPP_COMPILER = g++
CPP_FLAGS = -pthread -fno-strict-aliasing -g -O2 -g -fwrapv -O3 -Wall -fPIC

CUDA_COMPILER = nvcc -m64
CUDA_FLAGS = -Xcompiler -pthread,-fno-strict-aliasing,-g,-O2,-g,-fwrapv,-O3,-Wall,-fPIC
CUDA_FLAGS += -gencode arch=compute_$(COMPUTE_CAPABILITY),code=sm_$(COMPUTE_CAPABILITY)

CUDA_INCLUDE = /usr/local/cuda-$(CUDA_VERSION)/include
MGPU_INCLUDE = /usr/local/src/moderngpu/include
INCLUDE_FLAGS = -I$(CUDA_INCLUDE) -I$(MGPU_INCLUDE)

CUDA_LIB = /usr/local/cuda-$(CUDA_VERSION)/lib64
LINK_FLAGS = -L$(CUDA_LIB)

MGPU_SRC = /usr/local/src/moderngpu/src

TARGETS = thing

all: $(TARGETS)

thing: thing.co | mgpuutil.o mgpucontext.o
    $(CPP_COMPILER) $(CPP_FLAGS) $< $(LINK_FLAGS) -lcudart -o $@ $|

%.co: %.cu
    $(CUDA_COMPILER) $(CUDA_FLAGS) $(INCLUDE_FLAGS) $(LINK_FLAGS) -o $@ -c $<

mgpucontext.o:  $(MGPU_SRC)/mgpucontext.cu
    $(CUDA_COMPILER) $(CUDA_ARGS) $(INCLUDE_FLAGS) -o $@ -c $<

mgpuutil.o:  $(MGPU_SRC)/mgpuutil.cpp
    $(CUDA_COMPILER) $(CUDA_ARGS) $(INCLUDE_FLAGS) -o $@ -c $<

clean:
    rm -f *.o *.co $(TARGETS)
```

Comment: The error refers to running  `main`, but there is no target called main anywhere in those Makefiles. Are those the actual Makefiles you are using?

Comment: You should swap `ADD_SUBDIRECTORY(src)` and `ADD_SUBDIRECTORY(lib)` calls. Otherwise, when `TARGET_LINK_LIBRARIES(stuff LINK_PUBLIC thing thingKernels)` is called, library **targets** `thing` and `thingKernels` are not created, and CMake doesn't know about their location. `However, when trying to build the code with CMake (through CLion, if it matters), I get the following error:` - You get this error when **build** the project, not when you *run* it, am I right?

Comment: That kind of problem with CLion is already known for a long time and reported here: https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/CPP-10292

Comment: @talonmies I've changed some of the names, but there was never any target named `main`.

Comment: @Tsyvarev The error happens when I run it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I wrote the plugin [CLion CUDA Run Patcher](https://plugins.jetbrains.com/plugin/10691-clion-cuda-run-patcher)  to provide a temporary fix for this bug in CLion until JetBrains provides a proper fix as tracked in [CPP-10292](https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/CPP-10292).

The plugin was necessary because CLion ignored any target names from CMake including those specified by target property `OUTPUT_NAME`.

It's likely this problem won't be fixed until CLion has full CUDA support as tracked in [CPP-866](https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/CPP-866).

Comment: Just added a v1.1 which fixes running in Debug mode

Comment: The update seems to run into the same permissions issue again (in both run and debug modes).

Comment: The plugin has to be loaded by CLion after everything else (because it overrides some java code). Sometimes it gets loaded too early. If you get the permission error, close and re-open the project. (I'm assuming you have CLion >= 2018.1 and plugin >= v1.1 and the plugin is enabled)